# Interpolation of Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, interpolation

May I know how can I do the interpolation for a matrix in C++?
Eg: 
I have a 3x3 matrix 
{0 0 0
 0 1 1 
 0 0 1}
I wish to resize it to a 10x10 matrix using bilinear interpolation.

Any tips or references about this?

Answer (score 2):

What  you want to do is called image resizing using bilinear interpolation. Knowing that google is your friend. I would try using a C++ library for that purpose. This question covers all C++ imaging libraries: [Fastest C/C++ image resizing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873976/fastest-c-c-image-resizing-library) Any reasonable library should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to linearly interpolate between two things you need to embed (put) them in a common vector space and then "draw" the line between them.

I can't see a useful embedding of a 3x3 matrix and a 10x10 matrix in a common vector space...